# php array merge and convert to json

Tags: php, arrays, json, array-merge

I have two arrays (below). Is it possible to convert them into json string?

```
Array
        (
            [0] => size
            [1] => color
        )
Array
        (
            [0] => L
            [1] => Black
        )
```

Output structure should be:

```
[
   {"name":"size","value":"L"},
   {"name":"color","value":"Black"}
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Wut ? Have you searched `json_encode()`?

Comment: Split your task into 2 simpler ones: 1: to combine 2 arrays into a single one with a proper structure 2. To generate `json`. That's how we all solve our issues every day.

Comment: Array combine return me this Array
(
    [size] => L
    [color] => Black
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
$array1 = array('size', 'color');
$array2 = array('L', 'Black');

$jsonArray = array();
foreach (array_combine( $array1, $array2 ) as $name => $value) {
    $jsonArray[] = array('name' => $name, 'value' => $value);
}

echo $json = json_encode($jsonArray);
```

This gives you

```
[{"name":"size","value":"L"},{"name":"color","value":"Black"}]
```

Comment: $jsonArray = array();
foreach (array_combine(array_keys($product["option"]["name"]), array_values($product["option"]["name"])) as $name => $value) {
$jsonArray[] = array('name' => $name, 'value' => $value);
}
$json = json_encode($jsonArray);

Answer (score 0):

this here should work:

```
$json = json_encode( array_combine( $array1, $array2 ) );
```

Comment: Result is: {"size":"L","color":"Black"}

Comment: I need:  
{"name":"size","value":"L"},
   {"name":"color","value":"Black"}

Answer (score 0):

```
    $array1 = array('size', 'color');
    $array2 = array('L', 'Black');

    $result = array_combine($array1 , $array2);
    $json = array();
    foreach($result as $key => $val){
     $json[] = array('name' => $key, 'value' => $value);
    }
    $json = json_encode($json);
```

Comment: :) I don't know keys and values (eg. size or color)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work just how you want:

```
<?php
    $keys = array("size", "color");
    $values = array("L", "Black");

    $array = array();
    foreach ($keys as $i => $key) {
        $array[] = array(
            "name" => $key,
            "value" => $values[$i]
        );
    }

    $json = json_encode($array);

    var_dump($json);

    //string(62) "[{"name":"size","value":"L"},{"name":"color","value":"Black"}]"
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
$array1 = array('size', 'color');
$array2 = array('L', 'Black');
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array1);$i++)
   {
    $array3[]=array($array1[$i]=>$array2[$i]);
    }
echo json_encode($array3);

?>
```

Output:

[{"size":"L"},{"color":"Black"}]